# Doesn't work create swap on partition

Tags: swap

I want to create swap on /dev/sda3, but `parted -l` doesn't show me.

```
Number   Start   End      Size     File system   Name   Flags
1        1024kB  17.0GB   17.0GB   ext4
2        17.0GB  17.5GB   500MB    ext2                 boot, esp
3        17.5GB  20.0GB   2500MB
```

I executed this commands:

```
swapoff -a
mkswap /dev/sda3
swapon /dev/sda3
```

And what does `warning: wiping old swap signature` mean?

Answer (score 4):

The warning means those partition already had a swap signature, e.g. the `mkswap` command was already executed in the past in that partition.

As you executed `mkswap` again, it warned you it would be deleting an old signature.

As for `fdisk` does not showing it, it does mean the partition is not labeled as a partition device, however it does not mean it is not being used as such.

To put there the partition code for a swap partition, you can do:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
Commmand: t
Partition number: 3
Hex code: 82
```

Where:

- t is the command to label a partition with a code´
- 3 is the partition number
- 82 is the hex code por a swap partition.

After that,`fdisk -l` will show `sda3` as a swap partition.